# Плавное изменение цвета фона строки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, background

Подскажите пожалуйста, как плавно изменить цвет фона поднятой строки на дефолтный(погасить)?
На данный момент она гаснет(через setTimeout()), но резко.
выглядит вот так(при нажатии стрелы вверх, далее подсветка тухнет):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Js код, который поднимает отдел на один уровень вверх:

```js
//таймауты
var timeouts = {
  up_down: null
}

/* подниятие отдела */
$('#content').on('click', '.fa-arrow-up', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault()
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr') // текущая строка
  var $tbody = $(this).closest('tbody')
  // если строка уже сверху - ничего не делаем
  if ($tr.index() == 0) return

  $tr.insertBefore($tr.prev()) // поднимаем текущую строку на уровень вверх

  /* подсветка поднимающейся строки */
  $tbody.children().removeClass('info') // удаление у всех строк класса info
  $tr.addClass('info')
  clearTimeout(timeouts.up_down)
  // подсветку нужно будет погасить, поэтому удаляем info у поднимающейся строки
  timeouts.up_down = setTimeout(function() {
    $tr.removeClass('info')
  }, 1000)
  /**/

  // если элемент стал первым блокируем arrow-up
  if ($tr.index() == 0) {
    var $fa_arrows_up = $('.fa-arrow-up')
    $fa_arrows_up.removeClass('disactive-color')
    $fa_arrows_up.eq(0).addClass('disactive-color')
    return
  }

  // если элемент был последним(стал предпоследним)
  // ставим последней arrow-down disactive-color
  if ($tr.index() === $tbody.children().length - 2) {
    var $fa_arrows_down = $('.fa-arrow-down')
    // последней arrow-down ставим disactive-color
    $fa_arrows_down.eq($fa_arrows_down.length - 1).addClass('disactive-color')
    // убираем класс disactive-color у предпоследней arrow-down
    $fa_arrows_down.eq($fa_arrows_down.length - 2).removeClass('disactive-color')
  }

  // var send_data = { csrf_name: csrf_hash }

  // $.post(base_url('up_department'), send_data, function(res) {
  //  // pass
  // }, 'json')
  // .error(function(res) {
  //  // pass
  // })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Финансово-экономический отдел</td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-pencil redact-department"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-arrow-up disactive-color"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-arrow-down"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-remove rm-department"></a>
  </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>Технический отдел</td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-pencil redact-department"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-arrow-down disactive-color"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-remove rm-department"></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Есть ли у `tr` css свойство `transition`?

Comment: @Misha Saidov Нет, нету. Я, если честно, плохо понимаю как оно работает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `.info` есть `background: blue`, а у `tr` пусть будет `background: transparent`. Также к `tr` нужно добавить `transition:background 1s ease-in-out`. Все, анимация есть.

Comment: Спасибо! Резкое появление, плавное угасание - то, что нужно.